# How to test a spring controller using curl

Tags: spring-mvc, curl

Good Day Guys, I'm working on developing a web service. 
I created a controller named login

i want to test if this controller is working or returning something using curl. 
but i don't know the syntax or how to test it. 
Here is the code. 
devTest is the name of the project folder. 
and this is under the package app.controller.

Please help me. Thanks in advance

```
@RequestMapping(value = "login", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = {"Content-type=application/json"})
public @ResponseBody Map getResponse(@RequestBody Map request) {Map map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        public @ResponseBody Map getResponse(@RequestBody Map request) {Map map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String username = "";
    String password = "";
    String fullname = "";
    String imei = "";
    int cifid = 0;
    int accounts = 0;
    String firstAccount="";
    try {
        username = String.valueOf(request.get("username"));
        password = String.valueOf(request.get("password"));
        //imei = String.valueOf(request.get("imei")); 

        AuthenticObj auth = authentication.authenticate(username, password);
        if(auth == null) {
            map.put("success", false);
            map.put("message", "Invalid login.");
            return map;
        }
        if(!password.toLowerCase().equals(auth.getPassword().toLowerCase())) {
            map.put("success", false);
            map.put("message", "Invalid login.");
            return map;
        }

        cifid = auth.getCifid();
        firstAccount= accountManager.getFirstAccount(cifid);
        fullname = auth.getFullname();

    }catch(Exception e) {

        logger.error("ERROR", e);
        map.put("success", false);
        map.put("message", "An error occured. Response not processed.");
        return map;
    }

    map.put("cifID", cifid);
    map.put("firstAccount", firstAccount);
    map.put("success", true);
    map.put("message", "Response Received.");
    return map;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you mentioned project folder and java package name in the question.

To test with curl, you need to start your server and make a http request to your application (as you would normally do from a browser). Below is a sample curl command

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:8080/<your-context-root>/login -d 'username=yourusername&password=yourpassword'
```

You can see other curl examples [here](https://www.keycdn.com/support/popular-curl-examples)